# Creating Hover buttons in R igraph

Tags: html, css, r, graph, igraph

I am trying to create nodes which will change colour when the mouse hover over it.

I used R (igraph) to plot the nodes and to generate a network.

I then create a html template using the cat().

However, I am not sure how to link a css sheet to create the hover button which should lie on top of the nodes.

```
require(igraph)
htmlfile = file.path('~/Dropbox/Cambridge/PhD/ICAR/AIG/Map/html/', "page1.html")
cat("<html><h1>My first HTML page from R</h1>",file = htmlfile)
cat("\n<br>Hello Web World!", append = TRUE, file = htmlfile)
set.seed(1)
E.circuit.2 <- graph_from_literal(1--2:3:4:5, 2--3,3--2, 4--5)
E.circuit.2
coordinates <- layout_with_dh(E.circuit.2)
coordinates
plot(E.circuit.2) 

cat('\n<p><img src="map.png", align="center"></p>', append = TRUE, file = htmlfile)
cat("\n</html>", append = TRUE,file = htmlfile)
```

Comment: I have a basic knowledge in R,but I think this might help you [RGraphs](http://www.rgraph.net/docs/howto-index.html)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you only have to add:
`<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css"></head>`
after your `<html>` tag. Where you change mystyle.css to the stylesheet you would like to use.